# loss(y, y) != 0 (same labels and predictions, non-zero loss)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model  # TF 2.2.0

#%%#######################################################
ipt = Input(batch_shape=(128, 28, 28, 1))
x   = Flatten()(ipt)
out = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')

#%%#######################################################
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, model.input_shape)

pred = model(x, training=True)  # =False also works
loss = model.compiled_loss(pred, pred)
print(loss)
```

Output:

```py
tf.Tensor(1.9904033, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

What's the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just because of how the `categorical_crossentropy` loss works. If you try with `[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, it is zero. If you change `categorical_crossentropy` to `mse` in your original code, you also get zero.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf  # TF 2.2.0
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

ipt = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x   = Flatten()(ipt)
out = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy')

label = tf.one_hot([5,3,2], depth=10)
# tf.Tensor(
# [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]], shape=(3, 10), dtype=float32)
loss = model.compiled_loss(label, label)
print(loss) # tf.Tensor(1.1920929e-07, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

EDIT:

a `numpy` implementation of the `categorical crossentropy` loss would be:

```
import numpy as np 
def cce(y_label,y_pred):
    return np.sum(-y_label*np.log(y_pred))
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (10,))
print(cce(x,x)) # which yields values like 1.9904033
```

This shows why it is not zero, because you take the `log` of the prediction and multiply it by the label and take the negative. So the question to `what's the deal` is: `this is working as intended`.

Comment: I confirmed this via source code, but as-is, your answer doesn't explain it; if you include relevant details, I'll accept it.

Comment: I added an implementation for `CCE` in `numpy`, if this does not clear this up I will delete my answer.

Comment: Good enough; I also noticed you added an example of how to force `loss` to zero, which was of interest. I did rather ask this question in haste.